# Erro ao retornar resposta com o metodo pesquisar

Tags: java, mysql

Estou com problemas ao tentar fazer uma pesquisa no banco e retornar a resposta na tela.

Éssa é minha classe principal:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    pessoaDAO ps = new pessoaDAO();
    try {
        Pessoa pessoa = ps.pesquisarcpf("02317825277");
        if(pessoa == null){
            System.out.println("CPF não encontrado");
        }else{

            System.out.println("CPF: "+pessoa.getCpf());
            System.out.println("Nome: "+pessoa.getNome());
            System.out.println("Bairro: "+pessoa.getBairro().getNome());
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProjetoIntermediário2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Dai fiz  um metodo pra pesquisar usando CPF da pessoa. >:

```
public Pessoa pesquisarcpf(String cpf) throws SQLException{
    connection = FabricaConexao.pegarConexao();
    sql = "select * from pessoa inner join bairro where pesbaicep = baicep";
    Pessoa pessoa = null;
    preparedstatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedstatement.setString(1, cpf);
    resultset = preparedstatement.executeQuery();
     if(resultset.next()){
         pessoa = new Pessoa();
         pessoa.setCpf(resultset.getString("pescpf"));
         pessoa.setNome(resultset.getString("pesnome"));
         Bairro bairro = new Bairro();
         bairro.setNome(resultset.getString("bainome"));
         pessoa.setBairro(bairro);
     }
     return pessoa;
}
```

Quando peço pra compilar o codigo ele me retorna os seguintes erros :>

> Conexão bem sucedida mar 29, 2017 10:24:24 AM
>   projetointermediário2.ProjetoIntermediário2 main GRAVE: null
>   java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of
>   parameters, which is 0).  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3319)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3304)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:4016)
>     at modelo.DAO.pessoaDAO.pesquisarcpf(pessoaDAO.java:55)     at
>   projetointermediário2.ProjetoIntermediário2.main(ProjetoIntermediário2.java:17)

Answer (score 2):

Sua variável sql está errada. Troque `= baicep` por `= ?`

```
sql = "select * from pessoa inner join bairro where pesbaicep = ?";
```

Comment: Caramba amigo, na verdade estava bem mais errado, ao envés de pesbaicep, é pescpf que é onde ele vai efetuar a pesquisa, troquei aqui e funcinou como esperado. Muito agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

A resposta está na correção do código SQL, ficando

```
sql = "select * from pessoa inner join bairro on pesbaicep = baicep where pescpf = ?";
```